# increase inner gutter margin, but reduce outer margin for KomaScript-Book with Lyx

Tags: lyx, margins, printing, binding

I know this question has been asked many times over the years but I can't find any that answer the second requirement.

I have spent months preparing a book with Lyx using KomaScript-Book at 5"x9" page size. During the latter stages after the content was complete, I had to make minor edits and even force page breaks to reduce the "orphaned text" or "one figure per page" issue.

However, the printing preview has shown the inner margin is not enough, with too much lost to binding.

1. I'd like to increase the inner margin. I know I can do this in the Lyx document settings by entering a value for the "inner" margin. Doing this however messes up the layout (and increases page count?) and I'd have to go through the entire book content and rephrase some of it, and redo the page breaks.
2. **I'd like the entire text area to just shift left on the left pages, and right on the right-pages.** This way the flow is not changed, the number of pages remains the same, and the carefully rephrased content and page breaks work as before to create pages that look mildly professional.

I thought something like "+1cm" for the inner margin and "-1cm" for the outer margins would work but this isn't possible in Lyx.

So to repeat - I am fully aware questions about the inter margin, guttering, BCOR etc go back a decade, but I can't find any that just shift the text area left on left pages, right on right pages, to preserve the previous formatting.

I am happy to apply preamble if that is what it takes.

Comment: This seems relevant but I don't know how to implement it in Lyx https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/454576/binding-correction-without-changing-text-area

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am posting a solution here because the answer to this question is difficult to find on the web, I hope it helps others.

Based on the solution at the following link, I made it work with Lyx:
[Binding correction without changing text area](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/454576/binding-correction-without-changing-text-area)

- In the Lyx dialogue, Document -> Settings -> Document Class, add
  `areasetadvanced` to the Custom class options.
- Then in Document -> Settings -> LaTeX Preamble, add
  `\areaset[15mm]{\textwidth}{\textheight}`

I experimented with 10mm, 20mm, but found 15mm worked well with the print review.

This solution enabled me to keep the same text area as before, and didn't change any of the text flow.